# Efficiently convert a BufferedImage to an IplImage

Tags: java, c++, opencv

I'm trying to do efficiently convert a BufferedImage to an IplImage... could you give me any hint about the jni part?

Right now I do these steps:

I get the rgbs from the BufferedImage and I send them to the jni code where I do the following:

```
IplImage* getIplImageFromIntArray(JNIEnv* env, jintArray array_data,
    jint width, jint height) {
int *pixels = env->GetIntArrayElements(array_data, 0);
if (pixels == 0) {      
    return 0;
}
IplImage *image = loadPixels(pixels, width, height);
env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(array_data, pixels, 0);
if (image == 0) {   
    return 0;
}
return image;}};
```

and

```
IplImage* loadPixels(int* pixels, int width, int height) {
int x, y;
IplImage *img = cvCreateImage(cvSize(width, height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
unsigned char* base = (unsigned char*) (img->imageData);
unsigned char* ptr;
for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    ptr = base + y * img->widthStep;
    for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        // blue
        ptr[3 * x] = pixels[x + y * width] & 0xFF;
        // green
        ptr[3 * x + 1] = pixels[x + y * width] >> 8 & 0xFF;
        // blue
        ptr[3 * x + 2] = pixels[x + y * width] >> 16 & 0xFF;
    }
}
return img;}
```

But that is really slow... thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/):

```
IplImage.createFrom(aBufferedImage)
```

EDIT: There are a couple of reasons why your code is slow. The BufferedImage class was designed before NIO buffers came into fashion, so it uses standard Java arrays as backing buffer. Java arrays cannot be (safely) accessed directly from JNI, so by default, with the way you call GetIntArrayElements(), memory gets temporarily allocated and the array data gets copied into that new allocated memory, while ReleaseIntArrayElements() also copies back the data into the array, and frees the temporary allocated memory. And you also allocate a new IplImage on every call and make another copy when copying everything from that temporary buffer to the temporary IplImage. In a nutshell, your code allocates memory twice on the heap and copies the data three times. The recommended way to achieve the desired effect is instead to copy the data only once from inside Java, using direct NIO buffers. You can check what this looks like by peering into the relevant portion of the JavaCV's source code, namely IplImage.copyFrom(BufferedImage):

http://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/trunk/javacv/src/com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core.java#881

It branches into a lot of special cases, but basically it loops over all pixels to produce the copy. Adding a couple of threads to loop in parallel on multiple cores could also improve performance further...

After copying the data from Java, you may then use it directly from your native code if desired.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't say that I use those images for matching purpose. That is to say I use the find_obj.cpp demo and Surf to compare two images. I have seen JavaCV but I'm not sure that the ObjectFinder can match the two images in the same way the find_obj.cpp does. I would be glad if you could help me in that way, but maybe I need to create a new question... Thank you.

Comment: Hey Samuel, thank you for your detailed answer... it explains pretty much what I was asking.

Comment: Great! As far as find_obj.cpp is concerned, I used it as template to create ObjectFinder.java http://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/trunk/javacv/src/com/googlecode/javacv/ObjectFinder.java , so that should do what you want...

Comment: But you are not using flann to find the pairs, as fas as I know, it gives better results compared to the simple find, am I wrong?

Comment: I guess it needs to be updated to reflect the latest changes in that sample file, yes...